# Dev-C++ no encuentra el fichero del compilador

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Uso Dev c++, todo habia estado bien y nunca habia tenido ningun problema hasta ahora. Pero recientemente me encuentro con el siguiente error:

> C:\Users\Documents\g++.exe    [Error] CreateProcess: No such file or directory

¿Qué pasa? y ¿qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo? No sé si tenga algo que ver que recientemente cambié de Windows 7 a Windows Vista y que guardé los archivos del Dev-C++ cuando tenía Win 7 (a mi opinión no tiene nada que ver).

Comment: no se si sea tu problema pero instala el mingw, que es un paquete de compiladores y quizas tu computadora no los tenga, googlealo y listo

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes hacer es comprobar si tienes g++.exe en el directorio `C:\Users\Documents\`, que no va a estar (por eso recibes ese error). Entonces lo que debes hacer es actualizar Dev-C++ con el directorio adecuado. Para ello:

1. Localiza dónde se encuentra `g++.exe` en tu computadora. En mi caso, está directamente en el directorio en el que instalé Dev-C++, dentro de `MinGW64\bin`
2. En Dev-C++, pulsa en el menú de "Herramientas" (*Tools*)

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Selecciona "Opciones de Compilador..." (*Compiler options...*)
4. Ve a la pestaña de "Programas" (*Programs*)
5. Pulsa en el icono que hay junto a la fila de g++

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
6. Selecciona el directorio donde se encuentre `g++.exe`

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
7. Pulsa en "OK"

Ahora ya tienes configurada correctamente la ruta de `g++.exe` y no te debería dar errores cuando intentas compilar.